# Quote about sacred and profane thoughts

Tags: metaphysics

What is the name of the philosopher who said something about our thoughts roaming over things sacred and profane without a care for the morality of said thought? Any context would be appreciated.

Comment: I may have used the wrong words (sacred and profane).  The gist I got from the quote was that men's minds had no barriers unlike the real world .  I don't remember anything religious but I could be wrong.  New to philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

Émile Durkheim.

> The sacred–profane dichotomy is an idea posited by French sociologist Émile Durkheim, who considered it to be the central characteristic of religion: "religion is a unified system of beliefs and practices relative to sacred things, that is to say, things set apart and forbidden."
>
> <sub>From: [Sacred–profane dichotomy on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacred%E2%80%93profane_dichotomy); the quote from Durkheim 1915, p. 47</sub>

Comment: If there's a worse idea online than allowing other people to actually alter the *sense* of something posted by someone else, I haven't seen it. Civility prevents me from fully expressing myself at this moment. @Keelan I formally request and frankly insist you refrain from altering my posts from now on until the end of time. Your edit went far beyond the bounds of fixing a typo. If I'm on math.stackexchange and somebody with 100k rep and professional competence in the topic alters my post, that's one thing. This wasn't that. You don't like my style, don't read my posts.

Comment: I just realized its possible that you were being sincere and actually thought I would appreciate your edit. Let me correct you. I *deliberately* wrote a very abrupt answer because it took me no longer than five seconds to look up the information. The OP could have and most certainly should have done the same. Therefore I simply posted the direct answer to his question, along with the Wiki link and a minor self-deprecating joke as character filler. The fact that you totally misunderstood all of that is exactly why you are unsuited to edit my writing. You have knowledge but lack understanding.

Comment: I edited your post to make it fit the standard. It was an edit or a flag. If you don't want to contribute more than a link, comment, don't answer. It's not about style, it's about quality and standards. I indeed hoped you would appreciate my edit. There's a reason for the length threshold. If you're under it, you should think if you're doing the right thing. I don't think you can ask me to stop editing your posts based on one incident in which I wasn't even wrong. Through votes I have been given the privilege to edit by the community. (but a suggested edit like this would've passed as well)